# Android gradle sync failed

Tags: android, gradle, build, synchronization

I recently upgraded from Android studio 2.2.2 or 2.2.3 can't remember - to Android Studio 2.3.1 . Please can someone point me in the right direction as to how to get older projects running on this newer version of android studio ?

i tried changing the gradle build dependency to 2.3.1 as some suggested but that didn't help

thanks

Comment: upload error log on gradle console

Answer (score 0):

Your gradle may need some updates. When the android studio starts some update are suggested, they get the proper sdks, or version of the android you may be emulating.

Comment: There is an option for gradle updates, in Mac it is under de Android Studio menu, but in Windows may be under Preferences or Config.

Comment: Ok, no it's not related to gradle i think. i can build new projects just fine, but not sure how to get projects using a previous version of android studio to work, i followed recommended steps but it says hat gradle's dependency cache is corrupt. how do i fix this?